# Howto perform a MULTIPLY composite effect using Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have two different javax.swing.Icon objects and I want to a create new Icon which is the composite of these two. I want the composite to be a MULTIPLY effect, similair to what you would get in any photoshop-like image editing application when you choose that option. Specifically, per every pixel, if you have color Ca and Cb from image 1 and image respectively

Ca = (Ra,Ga,Ba)
Cb = (Rb,Gb,Bb)

the i want output to be

Cc = (Ra*Rb,Ga*Gb,Ba*Bb)

I want to do this on the fly (in realtime), so I've got to do this using only Graphics2D operations. I've looked at AlphaComposite and don't see that this can be done. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you already looked at the contents of java.awt.image? Is there some reason why BufferedImageFilter  and BufferedImageOp are not appropriate?

Answer (score 4):

Since most of the answers to this question point to a lot of off-site resources I thought I would provide a full implementation here. It's essentially the same as the large libraries of blending modes you may have seen, but I've taken away the abstraction for the purposes of only implementing the specific blend mode.

Some notes about the code below:

- To use simply `g.setComposite(MultiplyComposite.Multiply)`
- The `MultiplyComposite` class implements both `Composite` and `CompositeContext` since for my needs there is nothing different between the two. If you have a blending mode where parameters can be adjusted or the blending applies differently you will need to implement the two classes separately.
- This code only works on 32-bit "integer" buffers. You would need to modify this to work with 16-bit color (shifting and masking for 5/6 bits instead of 8)
- This code works with the last byte as the alpha channel. You'll need to modify the code to work with data without an alpha channel (24-bit).
- The shifting right by 8 in the `mixPixel` method is a quick way of dividing by 256. eg. `(a * b) >> 8` instead of `(a * b) / 256`
- Pixels are processed one row at a time, from left to right. If you have more memory you could modify this to process the entire buffer at once.

---

```
public class MultiplyComposite implements Composite, CompositeContext {
    protected void checkRaster(Raster r) {
        if (r.getSampleModel().getDataType() != DataBuffer.TYPE_INT) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Expected integer sample type");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void compose(Raster src, Raster dstIn, WritableRaster dstOut) {
        checkRaster(src);
        checkRaster(dstIn);
        checkRaster(dstOut);

        int width = Math.min(src.getWidth(), dstIn.getWidth());
        int height = Math.min(src.getHeight(), dstIn.getHeight());
        int x, y;
        int[] srcPixels = new int[width];
        int[] dstPixels = new int[width];

        for (y=0; y < height; y++) {
            src.getDataElements(0, y, width, 1, srcPixels);
            dstIn.getDataElements(0, y, width, 1, dstPixels);

            for (x=0; x < width; x++) {
                dstPixels[x] = mixPixel(srcPixels[x], dstPixels[x]);
            }

            dstOut.setDataElements(0, y, width, 1, dstPixels);
        }
    }

    private static int mixPixel(int x, int y) {
        int xb = (x) & 0xFF;
        int yb = (y) & 0xFF;
        int b = (xb * yb) / 255;

        int xg = (x >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int yg = (y >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int g = (xg * yg) / 255;

        int xr = (x >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int yr = (y >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int r = (xr * yr) / 255;

        int xa = (x >> 24) & 0xFF;
        int ya = (y >> 24) & 0xFF;
        int a = Math.min(255, xa + ya);

        return (b) | (g << 8) | (r << 16) | (a << 24);
    }


    @Override
    public CompositeContext createContext(ColorModel srcColorModel, ColorModel dstColorModel, RenderingHints hints) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    public static final MultiplyComposite Multiply = new MultiplyComposite();

}
```